# Leer archivo y depurar columnas con delimitador?

Tags: python

Hola Estimados estoy intentando leer un archivo con extension .rsl, pero tengo un problema como haria para depurarlo donde cada registro viene con la columna insertado y con un delimitador "|"

donde los campos de cabecera son rid,contact_info,call_time

por ejemplo:

```
rid=2023|contact_info=88650342309|call_time=7/1/2020 3:42:51 PM|
rid=2024|contact_info=88450342312|call_time=7/1/2020 8:42:51 PM|
rid=2023|contact_info=88950342374|call_time=7/1/2020 7:42:51 PM|
```

Comment: ¿En dónde quieres almacenar los datos? ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: ¿Depurar? ¿Quieres decir separar? ¿qué tal `for linea in fichero: trozos = linea.split("|")` ?

Comment: si lo que necesito es leerlo y depurar me refiero a que solo quede el registro del lado derecho despues del "=" en cada fila , y eliminar del lado izquierdo como el rid,contact_info,call_time,los datos sera insertado en una tabla de sql server.

saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes un texto que deseas dividir en partes por un delimitador dado, usas la funciòn `split(delimitador)`. El delimitador por omision es espacios. En este caso, usas `split("|")`.

```
linea = "rid=2023|contact_info=88650342309|call_time=7/1/2020 3:42:51 PM|"
print(linea.split("|"))
```

En este ejemplo, linea es un lista de partes encontradas:

```
['rid=2023', 'contact_info=88650342309', 'call_time=7/1/2020 3:42:51 PM', '']
```

Fijate que el ùltimo elemento de la lista está vacio. Este elemento aparece porque hay un separador "|" al final del texto de entrada.

Con las partes en una lista, puedes recorrerla y dividirla por el separador "=". Como puede haber elementos vacios o malformados, primero hay que asegurase de que venga un "=" en la parte:

```
for parte in linea.split("|"):
    if "=" in parte:
        llave, valor = parte.split("=")
        print(llave, valor)
```

Cada parte es separada en dos (llave y valor). Estoy imprimiendo ambas, para revisar, pero tú puedes descartar lo que no sirva.

Este código produce:

```
rid 2023
contact_info 88650342309
call_time 7/1/2020 3:42:51 PM
```